# How to skip with other further records when reached condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL issue. Lets suppose we have record:

[image: records]

In above record we need to select record with **Cancel** but only 2 starting not all with **Cancel**. There may be multiple `Cancel` on Top or anywhere.

Please help me to create query for that.

Comment: Is there any primary key like an id or any column that denotes the order of the rows?  If not then **starting** does not mean anything since tables are unordered sets of data.

Comment: Can you explicitly show the result you are trying to get?

Comment: @forpas yes there is primary key but we sort record with creation time and we want top records till non `cancel` status. Means only 2 records from image not 4th one

Comment: @Jeremy Please check Edited question

Comment: @ankit I still don't see the results you are expecting from the query.

Comment: @Jeremy I have query: `select case when ro.order_state='Cancel' then 1 else 0 end as isCancelStatus from public.t_repair_order ro where ro.claim_number='ABC1234' order by id desc;`. In this query i want to stop searching further records if we found non `Cancel` status.

Comment: @Jeremy Please let me know if still not understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where col = 'Cancel'
  and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where creation_date < t.creation_date and col <> t.col
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDZSUJsuNw31qwyp6nauYs/1).

Comment: Yes in fiddle it respond what i want but not working in my code. May be i am sorting records by id not by creation date.

Comment: Then instead of `creation_date < t.creation_date` do `id < t.id`

Comment: I use `select t.* from t_repair_order t
where t.order_state = 'Cancel'
  and not exists (
  select 1 from t_repair_order tt
  where tt.id < t.id and tt.order_state <> t.order_state
);`

Comment: But not working and yes fiddle showing my solution in all cases

Comment: Make a fiddle with your data and post the link here.

Comment: Have you got it?

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooook

Comment: On the table the minimum id is 6110 with order_state='Pending for Dispatch'. This is why you don't get any results. What do you want in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204524/discussion-between-ankit-and-forpas).

Comment: Try this: `select t.order_state, t.claim_number, t.id 
from t_repair_order t
where t.claim_number='SERCON201465' 
and t.order_state = 'Cancel'
and not exists (
  select 1 from t_repair_order tt
  where tt.claim_number=t.claim_number and tt.id > t.id and tt.order_state <> t.order_state
);`

Answer (score 1):

That should be working. I just ordered ASC on "column 1" but you can remove that line if you don't care about which index is selected.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE col2='Cancel'
ORDER BY col1
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: There may be more than 2 Cancel on Top

Answer (score 0):

If you want the initial set of "cancels", you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 = 'cancel' and
      t.col1 < (select min(t2.col1)
                from t t2
                where t2.col2 <> 'cancel'
               );
```

Comment: 1234 is just a row number not  a column in table. Please check image edit in question.

Comment: we sort record with creation time and we want top records till non cancel status. Means only 2 records from image not 4th one. There may be multiple `Cancel` records in top or anywhere

Comment: @ankit . . . "2 starting" implies that there is an ordering column in the table (tables represent *unordered* sets).  That is the column you should use.