# Why org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

I am trying to call particular query using Hibernate but i am getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 26 [select t.orderState from (from com.amtrust.decisionTree.model.TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='SERCON201474') t where t.orderState = 'Cancel'  and not exists (  select 1 from (from com.amtrust.decisionTree.model.TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='SERCON201474') tt  where tt.id > t.id and tt.orderState <> t.orderState)]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Please find below code part:

```
    String isCancelStatusQuery =
        "select t.orderState from (from TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='" + createOrder.getClaimId() + "') t" +
        " where t.orderState = 'Cancel'" +
        "  and not exists (" +
        "  select 1 from (from TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='" + createOrder.getClaimId() + "') tt" +
        "  where tt.id > t.id and tt.orderState <> t.orderState" +
        ")";

    List<Boolean> isCancelStatus = entityManager.createQuery( isCancelStatusQuery ).getResultList();
```

```
select t.orderState from (select * from TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='SERCON201474') t where t.orderState = 'Cancel'  and not exists (  select 1 from (select * from TrRepairOrder where claimNumber='SERCON201474') tt  where tt.id > t.id and tt.orderState <> t.orderState)
```

Comment: `from (from`? No, this is not valid JPQL.

Comment: `from (from` is wrong. When you have `from ( subquery ) t`, the `subquery` must be a `select` statement. You're missing the `select` part, i.e. it should be `select ... from ( select ... from ... ) t ...`

Comment: It's not valid any SQL, not just JPQL. You need a SELECT in that subquery somewhere.

Comment: @JacobH JPQL is not SQL. SQL is irrelevant.

Comment: Sir, this is a raw SQL string.

Comment: @Andreas @JB I used both `select t.orderState from (select * from TrRepairOrder` and `select t.orderState from (from TrRepairOrder` and got error for both

Comment: @JacobH Only if OP had called `createNativeQuery(String sqlString)`, but OP called `createQuery(String qlString)`

Comment: @Andreas Can you please give me corrected query?

Comment: Actually, no, because, as the duplicate answer says: *Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the `select` or `where` clauses.* --- Can't use subquery in the `from` clause, unless you switch to a *native* query. --- But I wonder .... looking closer at the statement ... why did you write it with subquery at all? `select 1 from (from TT where XX) tt where YY` should be `select 1 from TT where XX and YY`

Comment: Ok pedants... If there's no SQL then remove the tag.

Comment: @Andreas Query in Query is my requirement as per my requirement at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393936/6097074. Now if i am using `createNativeQuery` then i am getting `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`